# Override all products price when checkout if quantity more than specific quantity

Tags: php, opencart

My shop sells all products at `$ 25`. Then I want to do some discount based on total products quantity when customer checkout.

If a customer buys with total quantity more than 50, each product price will override from `$25` to `$22` for each product.

Something like below :

```
if (total_quantity > 80) {
   price for each product is $19
}

elseif (total_quantity > 50) {
  price for each product is $22
}
else {
  normal price
}
```

right now i can detect total quantity using `$this->cart->countProducts()` when customer checkout but now im not sure how to overide the price(*im sure this related with file controller\checkout\confirm.php*).

Hope someone can guide me on this.

Update :

Now i can filter all products price based on total quantity :

```
if ($this->cart->countProducts() > 3) {
    $product_price = '24.00';
}
elseif ($this->cart->countProducts() > 2) {
    $product_price = '23.00';
}
else {
    $product_price = $product['price'];
}

$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
    'name'       => $product['name'],
    'model'      => $product['model'],
    'option'     => $option_data,
    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
    'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_price, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
    'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_price, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
);
```

but now I'm not sure where to override the sub-total and total.

p/s: all product prices are fixed to $25

OC version: Latest Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution :

**catalog/controller/checkout**

Add below code before `$this->data['products'][] = array(`  (Line 361)

```
if ($this->cart->countProducts() > 80) {
    $product_price = '24.00';
}
elseif ($this->cart->countProducts() > 50) {
    $product_price = '23.00';
}
else {
    $product_price = $product['price'];
}
```

replace `$this->data['products'][] = array(` ... with

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
    'name'       => $product['name'],
    'model'      => $product['model'],
    'option'     => $option_data,
    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
    'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_price, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
    'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_price, $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
);
```

**system/library**

Add below code after `if (!$this->data) {` (Line 22)

```
//Count how many product in cart
$total_quantity = $this->session->data['cart'];
$total_product_in_cart = 0;
foreach ($total_quantity as $t_q) {
    $total_product_in_cart += $t_q;
}
$total_product_in_cart;
```

relace this `$price = $product_query->row['price'];` (Line 173) with

```
if ($quantity > 80) {
    $price = '24.00';
}
elseif ($quantity > 50) {
    $price = '23.00';
}
else {
    $price = $product_query->row['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more an answer for finding usages and methods rather than a direct specific answer.

If you are not sure how to of methods/vars a an object has available try outputting them with something like.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_class_methods($objectName));
print_r(get_object_vars($objectName));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

It will display a list of available methods.  It may have a method called something like setPrice() or something similar, at the very least it will give you more insight into some options available?